# How do i properly call the method that I created so that I'm able to use it within another?

Tags: java

I'm creating rock,paper,scissors with the methods:

```
 displayRoundResults()
 displayMatchResults()
 chooseHandShape()
 winningHand()
 //etc
```

The `winningHand()` method compares the characters & returns a value (0,1,2).
In my `displayRoundResults()` method I'm trying to call the `winningHand()` method into the `displayRoundResults()` method so it can take the integer from `winningHand()` and then add on to either one of the player's score depending on the returned value.

I think I have the methods written out well, I'm just stuck on how to call methods basically.

```
public class RockPaperScissors
{
    private final char _YES = 'Y';
    private final int _HIGH_BESTOF = 5;
    // ***********************************************************************

    // central method that holds the majority of the game's logic
    public void playGame()
    {
        char player1, player2; //used to display the handshape from method
        int playToWins;
        int winningHand;
        int p1Score = 0;
        int p2Score = 0;
        int numberOfRounds; 

        while (true) //add loop so that it keeps going until user decides to end the game

        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors..");
        //call playToWins Method to retrieve how many rounds will be played
        //playToWins(scan);

        //will output different outcomes until winner has won x amount of times (the number retrieved from playToWins)
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfRounds; i++)
        {
            player1 = chooseHandShape();
            player2 = chooseHandShape();

            //displays rock,paper, or scissor for each player
            System.out.println("P1: " + player1 + " P2: " + player2);

            //winningHand is called to compare the two values and then return an int (0,1,2)
            winningHand = winningHand(player1, player2);

            //displayRoundResult is called to calculate score for each round that is played
            displayRoundResult(p1Score, p2Score);
        }
        //displayMatchResult here
        //
        // majority of code should be here
        //scanner should be here
    }

    // display round results
    private void displayRoundResult(int p1Score, int p2Score)
    {
        int winningHand;
        //properly call winningHand method here

        if (winningHand == 1)
        {
            p1Score++;
        }
        if (winningHand == 2)
        {
            p2Score++;
        }
        //if winning equals ... then p1score goes up by 1 or p2score does
    }

    // display match results
    private void displayMatchResult(int round, int p1Score, int p2Score)
    {
        System.out.println("Player 1 has " + p1Score + " points & Player 2 has " + p2Score + " points"); 
    }

    // get what will be the round goal score
    private int playToWins(Scanner scan)
    {
        int numberOfRounds;

        System.out.println("Play round to? (Max is 5)");
        numberOfRounds = scan.nextInt();

        while (numberOfRounds > _HIGH_BESTOF)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a value between 1 and 5, your last input was incorrect!");
            numberOfRounds = scan.nextInt();
        }

        return numberOfRounds;
    }

    // given two hands choose which one wins
    // possible values for either parameter are 'R','P' or 'S'
    // use the RPS rules to determine the winner
    // return 0 for tie, 1 for player 1 win or 2 for player 2 win
    private int winningHand(char player1, char player2)
    {   
        int winningHand;
        char R,P,S;

        //tie
        if (player1 == (player2))
        {
            winningHand = 0;
        }

        //if player 1 wins
        if (player1 == R && player2 == S)
        {
            winningHand =  1;
        }
        if (player1 == S || player2 == P )
        {
            winningHand = 1;
        }
        if (player1 == P || player2 == R)
        {
            winningHand = 1;
        }

        //if player 2 wins
        if (player1 == S || player2 == R)
        {
            winningHand = 2;
        }
        if (player1 == P || player2 == S)
        {
            winningHand = 2;
        }
        if (player1 == R || player2 == P)
        {
            winningHand = 2;
        }

        return winningHand;

    }

    // method that randomly chooses a hand shape
    // returns 'R' for rock, 'P' for paper and 'S' for scissors
    private char chooseHandShape()
    {

        Random cChoice = new Random();
        Random pChoice = new Random();

        //0 = Scissors, 1 = Rock, 2 = Paper

        int cChoiceInt =  cChoice.nextInt(2);
        int pChoiceInt = pChoice.nextInt(2);

        //player 1 randomized
        char pChoice1;
        switch (pChoiceInt)
        {
        case 0:
            pChoice1 = 'S';
            break; 
        case 1:
            pChoice1 = 'R';
            break;
        case 2:
            pChoice1 = 'P';
            break;
        }

        //player 2 randomized
        char cChoice1;
        switch (cChoiceInt)
        {
        case 0:
            cChoice1 = 'S';
            break; 
        case 1:
            cChoice1 = 'R';
            break;
        case 2:
            cChoice1 = 'P';
            break;
        }

        return cChoice1;
        return pChoice1;
    }

    // Yes/No response
    // Returns true if the user enters a 'y' or 'Y'
    //
    private boolean yesResponse(Scanner scan)
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes(Y) or No(N)?");
        //scan.nextChar();
        return scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0) == _YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this part of a class declaration? Can you add the full code? All your methods are private so not reachable from outside the class. You should make at least one public and you can access that one

Comment: @Mihai sorry, I've added the full code. I'm not sure if they qualify as class declarations?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Before trying to call methods on it it should at least compile. Also add a main method and you can instantiate there your class and call your public method on that object

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you are definitely new to programming. Knowing this, I could recommend reading/watching as much guides as possible on the basics of programming.

Anyways, as you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods.asp), you need first and foremost to write the name of the function (you got that part right). But, functions in Java and many languages are also defined by parenthesis `()` which are used to pass parameters if there are any (but those are still required even with no parameters). Also, in the case of a function returning a value like you have, you need to assign its result to a variable if you want to use it afterwards (like in your case). This would be a proper way to do it :

`int thisRoundWinningHand = winningHand(player1Hand, player2Hand)`

BUT, note that this isn't correct in your current implementation as you are currently taking values of type `char` in your `winningHand()` function but your `displayRoundResults()` only receives the score? of both players as values of type `int`. Also, the name of the variable is different as you want to easily differentiate your function and variable (but it's not obligatory in Java).

There is much more things to point out about your code, which is why I again urge you to first read a proper guide (W3Schools which I linked here is good for beginners, you could start with the intro).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the useful stuff mentioned by Oliver Samson I notice an issue with displayRoundResult. The arguments are of primitive int types so when you call this method the values are passed by value not by reference. The statement p1Score++; will not have the expected result as it will only update the parameter value but not the original p1score. What you can do is define p1score and p2score as class variables:

```
public class RockPaperScissors
{
    private final char _YES = 'Y';
    private final int _HIGH_BESTOF = 5;
    // ***********************************************************************
    int p1Score = 0;
    int p2Score = 0;

    // central method that holds the majority of the game's logic
    public void playGame()
    {
        char player1, player2; //used to display the handshape from method
        int playToWins;
        int winningHand;
        int numberOfRounds; 
        ...
        displayRoundResult(winningHand);
      ...
    }
    // display round results
    private void displayRoundResult(int pWinningHand)
    {   
        if (pWinningHand== 1)
        {
            p1Score++;
        }
        if (pWinningHand== 2)
        {
            p2Score++;
        }
        //if winning equals ... then p1score goes up by 1 or p2score does
    }
```

In that case don't forget to reset the values at the beginning of a new game.

Good luck